# Delete a row from target spark delta table when multiple columns in a row of source table matches with same columns of a single row in target table

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I want to update my target Delta table in databricks when certain column values in a row matches with same column values in Source table.

The problem is when I have multiple rows in source table that matches one row in target Delta table.

This is a scenario where primary keys of two or more rows in source table matches with primary keys of one row in delta table.
I have tried to replicate the scenario below:

```
    sql="""
    MERGE INTO """ + targetTable + """ TGT USING """ + tempView + """ SRC ON TGT.id = SRC.id and TGT.category != SRC.category and TGT.startdt = SRC.startdt
    WHEN MATCHED THEN DELETE""" 

    targetDF = spark.createDataFrame([{"id": "5001","category": "N1","startDt": "2019-09-30 00:00:00.000"}])
    sourceDF = spark.createDataFrame([{"id": "5001","category": "E1","startDt": "2019-09-30 00:00:00.000"},{"id": "5001","category": "B1","startDt": "2019-09-30 00:00:00.000"}])
    targetDF.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("test.targetDF")
    sourceDF.createOrReplaceTempView("tempView")

    sqlOut=spark.sql(sql)
    display(spark.sql("select * from test.targetDelta"))
```

I have tried left join(targetTable left join sourceTable) on two tables where my id and startDt matches to get one row in my targetTable which I would like to delete but couldn't figure out how to do that.

```
    spark.sql("""Select TGT.id from test.targetDF TGT left join  tempView  SRC ON TGT.id = SRC.id and TGT.startDt= SRC.startDt""")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    package spark

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object ap1 extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("DataFrame-example")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  case class D(id: String, category: String, startDt: String)

  val targetDF = Seq(D("5001", "N1","2019-09-30 00:00:00.000"))
  .toDF()
  val sourceDF = Seq(D("5001", "E1", "2019-09-30 00:00:00.000"),
    D("5001","B1","2019-09-30 00:00:00.000"))
    .toDF()


  val res = targetDF.join(sourceDF, targetDF.col("id") === sourceDF.col("id") &&
    targetDF.col("startDt") === sourceDF.col("startDt")  , "left_semi")

  res.show(false)
//  +----+--------+-----------------------+
//  |id  |category|startDt                |
//  +----+--------+-----------------------+
//  |5001|N1      |2019-09-30 00:00:00.000|
//  +----+--------+-----------------------+

}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. left_semi join works perfectly. I will add spark.sql and pyspark version of it with Delete operation on target table

Answer (score 0):

I have executed the answer provided by @mvasyliv in spark.sql and and added the delete operation of the row from target table whenever row in target table matches with multiple rows in source table.

**spark.sql version**

```
   spark.sql("DELETE FROM MDM.targetDF a WHERE EXISTS(Select * from MDM.targetDF TGT left semi join  tempView  SRC ON TGT.id = SRC.id and TGT.startDt = SRC.startDt)").show()
```

**Pyspark Version:**

```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import *

    sql="""
    MERGE INTO """ + targetTable + """ TGT USING """ + tempView + """ SRC ON TGT.id = SRC.id and TGT.category != SRC.category and TGT.startdt = SRC.startdt
    WHEN MATCHED THEN DELETE""" 

    finalDF = targetDF.join(sourceDF, ((targetDF.id == sourceDF.id) & (targetDF.startDt == sourceDF.startDt)), "left_semi")

    finalDF.createOrReplaceTempView("tempView")

    sqlOut=spark.sql(sql)
    display(spark.sql("select * from test.targetDelta"))
```